# Reading BPS/Baud of an unknown serial device

Tags: serial-port, reverse-engineering

I am looking for a PC software program that is capable of calculating it's baud rate,  or BPS output, and this is a serial device that terminates to RS232. I have used RealTerm with all of its selectable baud rates but I feel this device has a specific rate. The data output isn't correct. The device is a JL Cooper MCS3 RS232 version. Any recommendations would be most helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the expected output on RS232 should look like? Does the device send on its own, or do you send commands and wait for the answer? If I know these things I could send you an example how to possibly find the correct settings by using our Docklight Scripting software and a small script. This would work in the free evaluation.

Comment: Simple hex data (0x34 0xE1)

Comment: I press a button and it sends a hex message, releasing the button also sends a different message

Comment: Is there a way it can send continously data? Or answer to something the PC sends? Because I am thinking of a "brute force" scanner that simply tries out all kinds of baud rates, even nonstandard ones and different parity settings. You cannot press a button constantly for this purpose.

Comment: There is only 1 LED on it attached to the button. If I press the play and record buttons simultaneously the light comes on, and off when I press stop. That LED is the only indicator on the device. I wouldn't see any other messages coming to it otherwise. There is a jog wheel when spun sends many continuous messages however that would need to be manually performed.

Comment: ok, tricky then, sorry for the delay. If you don't want to use dedicated hardware equipment that allows baud rate scanning, you could use a scope and measure the bit timing (if you have a scope available).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, check my answer here:  [Trouble trying to receive data from a serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457111/trouble-trying-to-receive-data-from-a-serial-port/50457412#50457412)
where I introduce an approach to this problem and what you can attempt before resorting to oscilloscopes or hex dumps.