# Trouble trying to receive data from a serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, ports

Hi I have a port connected to my pc which is sending data constantly and my objective is to receive data from it and print it out. The problem is I don't really know what type of data it's sending and how should I read it...

```
private void Button_Receive_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = false;
        #region
        string Port_Name = ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int Baud_Rate = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox_Standard_Baundrates.SelectedItem);


        COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate);
        #endregion
        COMport.ReadTimeout = 3500; //3.5 sekundes



        try
        {
            COMport.Open();
            if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
            {
                TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
                ReceivedData = COMport.ReadExisting();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));

                GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to Write to COM port ");
                GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true;
                COMport.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException SerialTimeOutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(SerialTimeOutException.ToString());
            COMport.Close();

            GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox_System_Log.Text = ReceivedData;
    }
```

Here's my code which tries to open the port and read the data. I tried debugging it and the ReadExising function returns a string of symbols which I can't understand. I tried a couple of ways but none of the worked and right now I'm desperate. I'm sorry there might be some unnescesarry lines of code cause I'm a complete beginner in SerialPort communications.

Comment: You need to test the baud rate first of all. I recommend using docklight or picocom or some tool in order to test output. If the data is not readable text but binary, well good luck..... you would have to guess baud rate AND format...

Comment: Do you know what device is on the other end of the connection? Does the vendor not have documentation?

Comment: You say you don't know what type of data it's sending, so are you sure it's text?  `ReadExisting()` returns the binary data received by the port, converted to a string using an encoding.  If the device isn't sending text, it's likely to return gibberish.  If it's sending binary data, use the `Read` method to capture it into a `byte[]` instead.

Comment: Also, if you don't know the bit rate or format, set your port to the maximum baud rate (115kbps), 8 data, no parity, no stop bits.  Read the data as bytes using `Read()` then look at the bit patterns in the binary data.  You can work out from that what the bit rate is supposed to be.

Comment: @Trevor albeit still ultimately inconclusive ('zeros' might be actual zeros... and in case of non text we can't know), that is a nice start. It certainly makes sense when trying to figure out baud for known data. +1

Comment: Ok so I went after @Attersson suggestion and tried it out in Docklight. It started printing out complete gibberish in ASCII format and some random numbers in Hex mode... Might be a broken device but I doubt it. What should I try next?

Comment: You need to perform a lot of tries. This is not yet conclusive. I will write an answer then...

Comment: @Attersson True not knowing what data to expect would be problematic, but even for unknown data, the pattern of how the bits are repeated should tell you the serial clock divisor, assuming the data is varying enough to see it.  If you have runs of 1s and 0s that are always multiples of 6 (for example), the bit rate is probably 19.2kbps (115kbps / 6).

Comment: @Trevor that is a reasonable assumption. Though. If the serial sends 1010101010101010 (etc) and we halve the baud rate getting 11111111111 this might be wrong. With oscilloscopes, though, yes... (or might I be getting confused?)

Comment: I have the device connected so I can see it's properties inside device manager. Baud rate: 9600bps  Data bits: 8 and Stop bits : 1.  Yet everytime i begin communication it starts showing gibberish and unknown symbols...

Comment: With docklight just log a long enough stream, save to binary file and then open it with a hex editor. And then.... good luck. I don't think binwalk could help, but it might.

Comment: @Attersson That would be the case only if the device is sending at a higher rate than the serial port is capable of, which is typically 115kbps.  That would be an interesting device, and mean that trying to connect it to that particular port is useless.  You're right that an oscilloscope would answer it in any case.  I think of the port bit rate as the "sampling frequency", so 10101 appearing as 1100110011 means I'm sampling twice as quickly as I should be.

Comment: @Attersson +1 for the "Open it with a hex editor".  I always like the "just look at the raw data with your eyes" type approach :)

Comment: @Trevor +1 to you too and further to your comment, I would run a tool in order to count repeating patterns (super easy in case of 14400 since it's a pattern of 8)

Answer (score 1):

All you can hope is the serial sends readable text. In which case your primary goal is to figure out the baud rate. Since you are a beginner, just install docklight (or maybe picocom or whatever working tool you have available). Try every baud rate starting from the highest (115200) [**check notes below**] and 8 data, going downwards and for every baud rate you check this way, mess around with stop bits and parity.

Alternatively (Thanks to Trevor for inspiration) you could run a tool to check for repeating 1s and 0s. For example if your stream is 110011001100000011110011 a good candidate is 115200/2. With 111000111000111000000111000111111111 a good candidate is 115200/3 etc

For the sake of completeness, the above method might be inconclusive, since the data "might" actually be 1100110011001100. Which would make little sense as this is a non efficient encoding, but coherently with the original problem, "we don't know" what the serial sends.

Now your hope is that you finally stumble upon the correct configuration and actually get readable text. If you do, you can move back to C# and set the correct configuration and resume your debug.

If you don't find any, this means the data is in binary format and we can have no certainty about the correct transmission configuration and the data content.

Your next bet would be saving a long enough log and open it with a hex editor.

---

**Notes:**

Even though you may receive some device info (e.g. baud rate 9600) the above steps are still recommended. Infact OP stumbled across wrong info whereas 9600 did not work, 115200 did.

115200 is considered the max for UART. But with proper interface you can reach 230400 and 460800... and possibly more. To make this answer future-proof, please **verify** what your **interface maximum** is as supported by both your hardware and serial driver.

Comment: Finally got some readable info from the device. 115200bps did the trick. Now I'm receiving data in a string format and I can begin working with the data. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help. Thanks to Trevor too

Comment: Nice, I was just trying to put it into words.  If I remember correctly, it's why all Hayes modem commands start with "AT".  It's a known, specific bit pattern that the modem looks for to immediately work out the bit rate and format of the host.  ["Autobaud"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_baud_rate_detection)